# How to store data in a file called questions.list

Tags: java, object, store, filewriter, printwriter

I am currently tring to store data in a file that is going to be called questions.list (a file object)However i am unable to this, i suspect there a few problems/missing parts in my code(as i have a very basic knowledge on objects). Could anyone please help me achieve this or help provide me with a better understanding of what i am doing wrong? thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Practice {
/**
*large amount of code
*/

String answer = alpha4;
System.out.println(answer);
}

/**
 * Method for saving information to a file 'questions.list'
 */
public static void printToFile(String userInformationToBePrinted) 
        throws IOException {
    PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(
            new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("questions.list", true)));

    fileWriter.append(userInformationToBePrinted + "\n");

    fileWriter.close();
```

I am guessing i am missing some code. If the question is not clear please feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: why not simply use `FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("questions.list");`

Comment: `i am unable to [do] this`. Why? Are you getting a compiler error? An exception? An empty file?

Comment: At the very least, give some indication of what your code is or isn't doing.

Comment: @RafaEl cause he likes the power of decorator pattern

Comment: Sorry, my problem is there is no compiler error but the question.list is no where to be found.

Comment: @nachokk yeah its makes the coder looks like an expert

Comment: @user3033321 means, you can run the program, but you cant find where the _question.list_ was saved?

Comment: Ya @RafaEl the program runs fine. but i dont think the question.list was saved. If anyone have a better approach to this please recomend another way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are saying that the progam runs without any error. Perhaps, your problem is that you can't find the file that you've just created.

By default, file created using `PrintWriter` / `FileWriter` will be saved in the directory where you run your program.

Note that you can specify where you want to save the file you created by adding folder path in your file name. for example, if you want to save the `question.list` in `D:\` you can do this:

```
PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(
                         new BufferedWriter(
                         new FileWriter("D:\questions.list", true)));
```